# About the regularity of the decomposition in prime factors

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic

**Definition of $\rho$.**

Let's consider a function $\rho$, acting on the prime decomposition of an integer $n$:

> $$\begin{matrix} \rho\colon & \mathbb N_{\geqslant 1}&\to &\mathbb N_{\geqslant 1} \\& n=\displaystyle\prod_p p^{\alpha_p}&\mapsto &\displaystyle\sum_p p\cdot\alpha_p .\end{matrix} $$

For example:

$$\rho(12)=\rho(2^2\times 3)=2\times 2+3=7.$$

**Context and various information.**

We can easily prove two things about $\rho$:

- $\forall m,n\in \mathbb N_{\geqslant 1},\quad \rho(mn)=\rho(m)+\rho(n)$;
- $\rho(n)=n\iff \text{ $n$ is a prime number}.$

We can also prove that

$$\rho(n)\geqslant \frac {2\log n}{\log 2}.$$

Here is an illustration of the sequence $\rho(n)$ for $n\in \{1,\ldots,100\}$. We can see that the born $\frac {2\log 2}{\log n}$ fits well. We can also notice that $\rho(n)=n$ if, and only if, $n$ is a prime number.

[image]

Here is the sequence for $n$ up to $10^3$. We can notice that things are ordered at the top and chaotic on the bottom.

[image]

If we plot the sequence for $n$ up to $10^6$, we will notice that this pattern seems to continue. Which raise my question:

> **Question.** What causes those lines to occur? What are the equations of those lines?

[image]

Comment: So-called integer logarithm or sopfr($n$) - see [OEIS A001414](http://oeis.org/A001414) - the top line has slope $1$ and is made up if primes and $4$

Comment: The next lines below the top lines will be the values for $2\cdot p$ ($\rho(n) \approx n/2$), $3\cdot p$ ($\rho(n) \approx n/3$) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top line is $y=x$ and consists of the primes and four because $\rho(p)=p$ if $p$ is a prime number, and $\rho(4)=4$.
The second to top line is $y=\frac{x}{2}+2$ and consists of all $2p$ where $p\in{P}$ and $p\neq2$, and the number 8. This is because $\rho(2p)=\rho(p)+\rho(2)=p+2$ and $\rho(8)=\rho(4)+\rho(2)=4+2$.

Let's skip to the 6th to top line. What is its equation?

It is actually $y=\frac{x}{6}+5$. Why $+5$ and not $+6$?

Well, if we take all $6p$ where $p\in{P}$ and $p\neq5$, we get $\rho(6p)=\rho(p)+\rho(6)=p+5$. The line also contains 24, because $\rho{24}=\rho(4)+\rho(6)=4+5$.

> To summarize, the nth line to the top has equation $y=\frac{x}{n}+\rho(n)$, and contains all $np$ where $p\in{P}$ and $p>2$, and $4n$.

I hope I answered all of your questions.