# About the study of an arithmetic function with peculiar behaviour

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic, experimental-mathematics

## Preliminaries.

*Apart from this first definition, what follows can be skipped for the reader in a hurry.*

**Definition 1.** Let's define a function $\Phi$ as such:

$$\begin{matrix} \Phi\colon&\mathbb N_{\geqslant 1} &\to &\mathbb N[X] \\ &n=\prod_{i} {p_i}^{\alpha_i} &\mapsto &\sum_i \alpha_i X^{i-1},\end{matrix}$$

where $(p_i)=(2,3,5,\ldots)$ is the ordered list of prime numbers and $\prod_i {p_i}^{\alpha_i}$ is the prime decomposition of $n$.

**Examples 1.**

- $\Phi(12)=X+2$
- $\Phi(3\,920)=2X^3+X^2+4$ since $3\,920=2^4\cdot 5\cdot 7^2$

**Remark 1.** We have $\Phi(1)=0$ and $\Phi(mn)=\Phi(m)+\Phi(n)$.

**Remark 2.** The application $\Phi$ is bijective, we will denote by $\Phi^{-1}$ its inverse.

---

## More context.

**Definition 2.** Let's the following function $\Psi$:

$$\begin{matrix} \Psi\colon&\mathbb N_{\geqslant 1} &\to &\mathbb N \\ &n &\mapsto &\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\sqrt n}\Phi^{-1}(\Phi^{(k)}(n)),\end{matrix}$$

where $\Phi^{(k)}$ is the $k$-th derivative of $\Phi\in \mathbb Z[X]$.

**Example 2.**

- $\Psi(10)=4$
- $\Psi(25)=124$
- $\Psi(30)=54$

Let's plot the first values of $\Psi$:

[image]

**Remark 4.** We can show that $\Psi(n)\to \infty$ since for all $n$, $\Psi(n)\geqslant \log n/\log 2$.

## The question.

I am interested in the values which make this function $\Psi$ "explode".

Let's comprehend what I mean by "explode" by looking at those graphs:

[image]

[image]

[image]

We already saw that $\Psi(25)$ was quite bigger than the other $\Psi(n)$ for $n$ close to $25$, now we see that $49$, $98$, $121$ and $169$ are such values, where $\Psi(n)$ gets significantely big for those values.

Appart from $98$, which is $49\times 2$, all of those values seem to be equal to $p^2$ where $p$ is a prime number.

Which is why I make the following assumption:

> **Conjecture 1.** $\Psi(n)$ gets significantly bigger than any $\Psi(k)$ for $k\leqslant n$ is, and only if, $n$ is the square of a prime number.

So my **questions** are the following:

- Do you have any leads on how to prove conjecture 1?
- I fail to make more tests than that since the numbers are getting huge, feel free to share your work.
- Can we find some kind of a formula for $\Psi(n)?$
- Can we bound $\Psi$ in a better way than remark 5?

---

I proved the following remark, where $\pi(n)$ denote the number of primer numbers less or equals to $n$ and $\lfloor.\rfloor$ is the floor function, but I am not really satisfied with this bound.

**Remark 5.** We have for all $n$:

$$\Psi(n) \leqslant \lfloor(\pi(n)+1)\log(\pi(n)+1)+\log(\log(\pi(n)+1))+13\rfloor!.$$

Comment: Please remove $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $\Phi^{-1}$ and find a simpler expression for $\Psi(n)$ of the kind $\Psi(n) = \prod_{p^k \| n} f(k,p)$. Then I don't understand the motivation for this functions $\Psi$ and I don't think you can say something interesting about such weird things. Did you study Daniel Fischer's answer to your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2319801/some-regularity-in-the-prime-decomposition) ?

Comment: @reuns I will try to find a simpler expression, but the motivation does not seem to arbitrary to me since the mapping $\Phi$ seems quite canonical. Yes, I studied Daniel Fischer's answer, great answer!

Comment: @reuns What I mean by *canonical* is that it is the only mapping satisfying $\Phi(1)=0$ and $\Phi(mn)=\Phi(m)+\Phi(n)$.

Comment: I computed $\Psi(25) = 122$ , so please show me how you've got $124$.

Comment: Thanks for such beautiful questions, love your posts.

Comment: First $\Phi(12)=x+2$ and not $x+1$ ,also please show us how you computed $\Psi(25)$ or $\Psi(10)$ ?!.

Comment: @Ahmad Thank you. I think my definition of $\Psi$ is not very clear, I will edit. I think what you are missing about $\Psi(25)$ is that $\Phi(1)=0$, so $\Phi^{-1}(0)=1$. Tell me if you don't see what I mean. You are absolutely right about $\Phi(12)$, I will edit.

Comment: I don't see what that mean. Why you don't follow my advice above ?

Comment: @reuns I meant for Ahmad, since he found $122$ instead of $124$ for $\Psi(25)$, I think this is what he needs. About your advice, I like to see the bijection with $\mathbb Z[X]$, since this is how I find it natural. But if you found an expression of the form you said, feel free to post it here :)

Comment: Come on.. No this is not natural. What is natural is to write $n = \prod_{p^k \|n} p^k$ or $n = \prod_i p_i^{e_i}$. Here you have $\Psi(\prod_i p_i^{e_i}) =   \prod_i p_{i}^{\sum_j c_{i,j}e_{i+j}}$ for some constants $c_{i,j}$.

Comment: $\sqrt n$ as the summation upper limit in the definition of $\Psi$ seems arbitrary, and that's what ultimately causes explosions on **squares of primes**. The natural thing would be to take the derivatives until the polynomial hits 0, and then $\Psi$ would explode on **primes**.

Comment: @IvanNeretin That is what was initially thought, I will look at what it does with this rule.

Comment: @reuns Yes you are right, I don't see any simpler way to describe those constants $c_{i,j}$ though...

Comment: Start by defining them, possibly in term of the upper limit $\sqrt{n}$. What Ivan said follows from a **concrete** definition of your function.

Comment: @reuns Ok, I will try to do that :)